# Cassandra: Does SELECT COUNT(*) differ between versions 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: cassandra

I'm migrating data between a Cassandra cluster on version 2.2.4 to one on 3.11.3 by exporting the table as a CSV file and using it to create a new table in the new cluster. I'm using `SELECT COUNT(*)` to verify that the data has been copied over correctly but am seeing a discrepancy in the number of rows. Could this be because of the difference in versions? Is there anything else that would explain it? Thanks!

Here are the steps I'm running through:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_cass2
count
-------
  7951
(1 rows)

COPY table_cass2 TO '/tmp/table.csv'

COPY table_cass3 FROM '/tmp/table.csv'
Using 15 child processes  
Starting copy of <table> with columns [..].   
Processed: 7951 rows; Rate:    3741 rows/s; Avg. rate:    6045 rows/s
7951 rows imported from 1 files in 1.315 seconds (0 skipped).

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_cass3`  
 count  
-------
  7919
(1 rows)
```

Comment: same with CL.ALL?

Comment: Make sure you are running select query with same consistency on both instance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, someone else on my team confirmed that it is normal for there to be a small but consistent difference in results for `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries between different instances of Cassandra.

Comment: unless you're using quorum for both reads and writes (then you should have zero inconsistencies)